# How to get path of images with IOS 16 image picker SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, imagepicker, ios16, photosui

Good day,

How do I get the path of images from the ios 16 Photos Picker(PhotosUI Library) as I am trying to store the path in a json file to retrieve later to display

I have a form with a image picker and I want to store the path in json file and then later retrieve the path from the json file to show the image on another view.

Comment: You don’t, you get the data and you can save that somewhere and get the url like that.

Comment: @loremipsum how do I get the data and the url

Answer (score 0):

There are no images and no paths. The photo library is a database.

You can get the photo asset's *identifier* if you have permissions, and then you can use that elsewhere to fetch the same photo from the database.

Comment: how would I get the identifier

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier